# How to catch errors or exceptions with Abraham's twitteroauth library?

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

Using https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth:

```
function getTwitterFeed($token_array){
    require_once('twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');
    $oauth_token = $token_array['access_token'];
    $oauth_token_secret = $token_array['access_token_secret'];
    $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
    $response = $connection->get("statuses/user_timeline");

    //...do stuff with the response
}
```

I want to catch errors or exceptions for authentication problems (invalid token or token secret) and/or "rate limit exceeded."

I can't find anything on error handling for this library anywhere.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Look into the [Exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) part of the PHP manual, the library uses them extensively.

Basically they will look like this:

```
try {
    // your code here
} catch (OAuthException $e) {
    // your error handling here
}
```

the `OauthException` class is the what the library uses for every throw.

#### Edit0:

Unfortunately the errors returned from the actual twitter API not converted into exceptions by the library so you will have to check the return values from get() and other calls, and look for the "error" key, errors will look something like this:

```
object(stdClass)[5]
   public 'error' => string 'Could not authenticate you.' (length=27)
   public 'request' => string '/1/account/verify_credentials.json?aauth_consumer_key=CONSUMER_KEY_HERE&oauth_nonce=cfbf6a55b26683750a166f14aeb5ed84&oauth_signature=c96MciQcODQD5jUAkyrAmSxXa0g%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1342379970&oauth_token=alma&oauth_version=1.0' (length=258)
```

also it will set the API instance's http_code code property to the response's http status, if that's not 200 it will indicate error.

#### Edit1:

I've created a [fork](https://github.com/complex857/twitteroauth/commit/4f497e10a17e90895712250a899f943d14b23512) of the library that will generate exceptions for every request that returns non 200 HTTP status, the exception's code will be the http status that twitter returns and message is the message (if exists), twitter's [http error code listing](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/error-codes-responses) will help decode the errors.

Also introduced a new Exception subclass for convenience named `TwitterOauthException`, every exception that thrown by the library subclasses this one.

Comment: Do I need to declare OauthException somewhere?  I've intentionally passed bad tokens as a test and not a single error gets thrown.

Comment: Nope, that class is declared in the twitter lib's OAuth.php file. You can try to catch every exception with the class `Exception` since every throwable exception must extend that class, it will catch everything that gets thrown.

Comment: I apologize, looks like I've spoken too soon. The errors returned from the actual twitter API returned as stdObjects and not converted to exceptions by the lib, edited the answer.

Comment: So do I look for $response['error'] then parse it based on a string compare?  Will I get a response regardless of failed credentials?

Comment: In my understanding yes, but i would probably wrap the client lib and extend its `http` method to throw exceptions when response's http status is not 200 OK. I've created a fork that does just that.

Comment: @KeepMove Abraham's lib is the best out there, but there is still no exceptions support.